# Performance point not working correctly in a SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-2007, performancepoint

After running a script from the security team that changes files permissions and also isntalls some hotfixes, performance point stopped working on my SHarePoint site. The Dashboard Viewer web part does not show the background of a graph we use, and when adding a new web part of this kind into the page the image icon of it does not appear in the web part list.

Any idea of what folder I should give access to and what user? I believe it has to do with file permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happened because UrlScan was installed on the server and Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.WebParts directory contains dots in its name. I modified UrlScan config file to let it allow dots in the URL and it started working again.